# what is the standard ulr for wordpress plugin development?

Tags: plugin-development

I developed a plugin to view exam data in tabular format. I wan to show **add new** button at top left corner. This button will redirect a url. I generated this url in two way:

```
  <a href="<?php echo plugins_url('includes/add_exam.php',__FILE__); ?>" class="page-title-action">Add New</a>

       <?php echo sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s" class="page-title-action">Add New</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'add'); ?>
```

This tow lines generate two url as like:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/absb_online_exam/includes/includes/add_exam.php
```

and

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=exam_list&action=add
```

respectively. After redirecting this I will do rest of coding to add new entry. I am new in wordpress. Hence I am afraid of standard of wordpress best practice. Any suggestion. If my two approach is wrong please give some instructions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one of the best practice is to not link to a PHP file in plugin (or a theme). to add a page in the backend you can try with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ and if you want to generate something else that HTML, you can use that : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins